# How to enforce function signatures in JavaScript in the Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to get the monaco-editor (v0.13.1) to check function signatures in JavaScript. By using the code below, I at least get IntelliSense to show the intended signature, but no error is shown:

```
// validation settings
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: false,
    noSyntaxValidation: false,
});

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: false,
    noSyntaxValidation: false,
});

// compiler options
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES6,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    allowJS: true,
});

var jsCode = `
/**
 * @param {string} a
 * @param {number} [b]
 */
function foo(a, b) {

}

foo(1); // here should be an error!
`

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: jsCode,
    language: "javascript"
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: see <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195952/can-i-prevent-passing-wrong-number-of-parameters-to-methods-with-js-lint-js-hin>. Seems not possible with dynamically typed languages - like Javascript. In C++ and other statically typed languages, for sure it is normal practice.

Comment: Your answer is not related to the monaco editor. That editor is powered by TypeScript internally and for that reason can do exactly that. Inside VSCode it works for javascript and in typescript mode it works in the browser. Just not in the browser when I use javascript mode.

Comment: @DGriesel, this is completly correct for JS code! You are not in TypeScript mode! Please, learn the JS language.

Comment: @Bharata: What does learning a language have to do with wanting to use an existing editor feature? If you don't have anything constructive to add, please don't... Since I found the answer in the meantime, I posted it below.

Comment: @DGriesel, you can see: you got your answer there on 7. August and would not post it here without my comment. And this answer is not correct because the checking will be done not only for function signatures in JavaScript – this will be done for whole JavaScript code with TypeScript rules. This is completly wrong!

Comment: And what if I told you that is exactly what I wanted to achieve? noSemanticValidation and noSyntaxValidation are set to false... Only the function signatures weren't being checked in JS mode. You can rest now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other posters seem to miss the point of my question, I'll answer it myself.

It is possible with the monaco-editor to type-check JavaScript code, VSCode does it and that is what I intended to do.

In order to do so, the editor model must be "typescript", the file URI needs a ".js" extension and "allowJS" and "checkJS" compiler options must be turned on:
https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/989#issuecomment-411027528